# Javascript clipboard function

Tags: javascript

I required clipboard copy/paste function. Not for the Image only for the Text.

Please help.

Regards
Mahadevan

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it with javascript, you must use flash for it.

http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ocanal. I use this plugin .http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard
But before post a question I suggest to search in `Stackoverflow` and `google` for your problem.

Comment: Hi all 

Thanks for the reply.

but i want only in javascript.

Thanks in advance